# Excluir setores e seus descendentes - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho a seguinte **estrutura** de tabela:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setores` (
  `set_cod` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `set_base` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `set_setor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `set_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `set_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`set_cod`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Neste caso, eu posso adicionar 3 níveis de setores, como abaixo:

[image: Estrutura de setores]

Onde este azul é o setor principal, cinza represento o subsetor e o branco represento um terceiro setor.

Pois bem, minha questão é: Como eu faço pra que ao excluir o setor Principal, exclua todos os outros setores? E se eu excluir somente o subsetor? 
Há alguma forma de fazer isto usando `left join`?

Pra eu listar conforme está abaixo, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
# Busca Setores
public function busca_setores(){

    $this->db->where("set_base", '0');
    $this->db->order_by("set_setor", "ASC");
    $consulta = $this->db->get('setores')->result();

    foreach($consulta as &$valor){

        $this->db->where("set_base", $valor->set_cod);
        $valor->subsetor = $this->db->get('setores')->result(); 

        foreach($valor->subsetor as &$subsetor){
            $this->db->where("set_base", $subsetor->set_cod);
            $subsetor->subsubsetor = $this->db->get('setores')->result();
        }

    }

    return $consulta;   
}
```

Será que dá pra adaptar esta realidade, pra montar a exclusão por setores?

Comment: Mano se entendi bem acho que isso seria definido na criação da chave estrangeira dessas subs, colocando um ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Hmmmm, ai eu só passaria um delete where set_cod = x, e o restante o banco de dados faria? como seria o procedimento?

Comment: mas é uma tabela só, daria certo igual? consegue exemplificar?

Comment: Sendo na mesma tabela não sei como seria cara, mas não deve ser muito diferente disso: FOREIGN KEY (coluna_chave_entrangeira) REFERENCES setores (coluna_chave_primaria) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Sim, o banco de dados cuidaria de ir deletando o resto, mas reve isso ai pois desse maneira acho que pode acabar causando um efeito cascata maior do que o esperado sendo tudo uma só tabela.

Comment: Qual coluna representa o "parent id"? A coluna "set_base" ou "set_setor"?

Comment: set_cod = cod do setor, set_base = cod do setor principal dentro do subsetor, set_setor = nome do setor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma ideia é usar o `ON DELETE CASCADE` na chave-estrangeira (da tabela para ela mesma):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setores` (
  `set_cod` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `set_base` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `set_setor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `set_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `set_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`set_cod`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `setores`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `relaciona_pai` FOREIGN KEY (`set_base`)
    REFERENCES `setores` (`set_cod`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

O SQL para a exclusão seria este:

```sql
/* Vamos supor que 5 é o código do setor pai que você quer excluir. */
DELETE FROM setores WHERE set_base = 5;
```

E note que no código acima eu usei `ENGINE=InnoDB` ao invés de `ENGINE=MyISAM`. Isso é importante porque o MyISAM não suporta o conceito de chaves estrangeiras. Embora o MySQL as mantenha nas definições das tabelas, as restrições de integridades correspondentes não são respeitadas pelo MyISAM, que as ignora completamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43663/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra possibilidade é resolver isso com uma `trigger`. Essa abordagem é mais difícil de se manter, mas dispensa a necessidade de se ter o auto-relacionamento da tabela (mas você pode optar por tê-lo mesmo assim).

```sql
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `apagar_subsetores` BEFORE DELETE ON `setores` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM setores WHERE set_base = old.set_cod;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: E nesta forma, como seria o SQL?

Comment: @AndréBaill Da mesma forma que na outra.