# Campo set_base NULL > Conforme SQL

Tags: sql

> Questão de referência:
>
> [Excluir setores e seus descendentes - PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146145/excluir-setores-e-seus-descendentes-php)

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setores` ( 
`set_cod` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`set_base` int(10) NOT NULL, 
`set_setor` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
`set_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`set_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (`set_cod`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 

ALTER TABLE `setores` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `relaciona_pai` FOREIGN KEY (`set_base`) 
REFERENCES `setores` (`set_cod`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Porém, quando eu adiciono um novo registro, o set_base vem NULL.

SQL de insert:

```
`INSERT INTO setores(set_cod, set_base, set_setor, set_data, set_status) VALUES (1,1,"raiz",1,1);`
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso resolver a questão?

Comment: `INSERT INTO setores( set_base, set_setor, set_status) VALUES (1,"raiz",1);` você inseriu assim? pois o set_cod é auto incremento e o set_data é o Current_Timestamp portanto não precisa inserir.

Comment: Isso, inseri assim sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deves estar a fazer alguma coisa mal no PHP, porque aqui funciona direitinho, ora vê o [exemplo no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3bf1/2).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setores` ( 
`set_cod` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`set_base` int(10) NOT NULL, 
`set_setor` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
`set_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`set_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (`set_cod`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 

ALTER TABLE `setores` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `relaciona_pai` FOREIGN KEY (`set_base`) 
REFERENCES `setores` (`set_cod`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO setores(set_cod, set_base, set_setor, set_status) 
            VALUES (1,1,"raiz",'0');
INSERT INTO setores(set_cod, set_base, set_setor, set_status) 
            VALUES (2,1,"filho1",'1');
INSERT INTO setores(set_cod, set_base, set_setor, set_status) 
            VALUES (3,1,"filho2",'1');
INSERT INTO setores(set_cod, set_base, set_setor, set_status) 
            VALUES (4,1,"filho3",'0');

SELECT * FROM setores WHERE set_status = '1';
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E também insere direito mesmo sem `set_cod`, [vê o exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57ea1f/1).

```
INSERT INTO setores(set_base, set_setor, set_status) VALUES (1,"raiz",'0');
INSERT INTO setores(set_base, set_setor, set_status) VALUES (1,"filho1",'1');
INSERT INTO setores(set_base, set_setor, set_status) VALUES (1,"filho2",'1');
INSERT INTO setores(set_base, set_setor, set_status) VALUES (1,"filho3",'0');
```